# Selecting subjects with specific waveform types

Tags: mimic-iii

I would like to run a query that selects all subjects containing specific waveform types such as II.

A few months ago I run a script on the WAVEFORM_SEG_SIG table, but the table no longer exists. Is there a way that I can get such information?